# CSS transform not taking duration

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am doing some simple CSS animation.

This is my CSS:

```
#contactBtn {
  transition: width 1.5s, height 1.5s, transform 1.5s;
}
```

Then in my JS on click I do:

```
contactBtn.style = "width: 61em; height: 35em; transform: translateX(0)";
```

The width and height animate as expected, taking 1.5s to increase from their original. The transform also occurs - the element moves to where I expect it to be. But it jumps instantly rather than delaying.

So far have only tested in Chrome.

I have tried splitting out the CSS, as below, without success:

```
#contactBtn {
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
  transition-property: width height transform;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I have test it and works fine! what is your translateX value before change it ?!

Comment: It doesn't have a translatX value before - its initial position is set by margin-left, against another element which in goes to display:none when this element is clicked

Comment: transitions work only when you have an old value, that's how they work! so you should set the value for transition before setting new one... you could calculate with javascript...